# SPFx web part to add Text and show it inside a Popup when clicking on a button

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience

I am trying to achieve this using SPFx web part:

1. The web part will provide a Button and a Text field.
2. The user add the Web Part >> edit it >> enter the text inside the text field (inside the setting page) >> save the web part>> then the web part will render a button >> if the user clicks on the button a popup will be shown with the entered text.

Now I found this link, [Mode pop up In SPFx](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/conecpt-of-react-portal-in-spfx/) which almost achieves what I am looking for, except that the Popup text inside the example is been hard-coded inside the `.tsx` file.

So, what are the steps to make the Popup text configurable inside the web part settings instead of been hard-coded?

Here is my `ReactPortalWebPart.ts` file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import * as strings from 'ReactPortalWebPartStrings';
import ReactPortal from './components/ReactPortal';
import { IReactPortalProps } from './components/IReactPortalProps';

export interface IReactPortalWebPartProps {
  description: string;
}

export default class ReactPortalWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IReactPortalWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IReactPortalProps> = React.createElement(
      ReactPortal,
      {
        description: this.properties.description
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

and here is the `ReactPortal.tsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react';  
    import { IReactPortalProps } from './IReactPortalProps';  
    import Myportal from "./Myportal";  
    export default class ReactPortal extends React.Component<IReactPortalProps, {}> {  
      public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactPortalProps> {  
        return (  
          <div >  
          <Myportal/>  
          </div>  
        );  
      }  
    }
```

Here is the `Myportal.tsx`:

```
    import* as React from "react";  
    import usePortal from "react-cool-portal";  
    import "./mystyle.scss";  
    const  Myportal = () => {  
     // const { Portal } = usePortal({ containerId: "my-portal-root" });  
      const { Portal, show, hide } = usePortal({ defaultShow: false,containerId:"my-portal-root" });  
      const handleClickBackdrop = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {  
        const { id } = e.target as HTMLDivElement;  
        if (id === "modal") hide();  
      };  
      
      return (  
            <div className="App">  
         
          <button className="btn" onClick={show} type="button">  
            Who we are 
          </button>  
         &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
          <button className="btn" onClick={show} type="button">  
            Our value 
          </button> 
          <Portal>  
            <div  
              id="modal"  
              className="modal"  
              onClick={handleClickBackdrop}  
              tabIndex={-1}  
            >  
              <div  
                className="modal-dialog"  
                role="dialog"  
                aria-labelledby="modal-label"  
                aria-modal="true"  
              >  
                <div className="modal-header">  
                
                  <button  
                    className="modal-close"  
                    onClick={hide}  
                    type="button"  
                    aria-label="Close"  
                  >  
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>  
                  </button>  
                </div>  
                <div className="modal-body">  
                 <h1> Who we are</h1>
<h3>.................................................</h3>
Our overriding purpose is to dramatically improve the reliability, efficiency........
                </div>  
              </div>  
            </div>  
          </Portal>  
        </div>  
          
      );  
    };  
    export default Myportal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your SharePoint framework web part configurable, you have to use the property pane configuration.

Make below changes in your solution to make the `modal-body` text configurable:

Change `getPropertyPaneConfiguration()` method in `ReactPortalWebPart.ts` file to:

```
protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                }),
                PropertyPaneTextField('modalBody', {
                  label: "Modal Body"
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
}
```

Change `render()` method in `ReactPortalWebPart.ts` file to:

```
public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IReactPortalProps> = React.createElement(
      ReactPortal,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        modalBody: this.properties.modalBody
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
}
```

Add `modalBody` property to `IReactPortalProps` interface in `IReactPortalProps.ts` file like:

```
export interface IReactPortalProps {
    ... //your other properties;
    modalBody: string;
}
```

Change `ReactPortal.tsx` file to:

```
import * as React from 'react';  
import { IReactPortalProps } from './IReactPortalProps';  
import Myportal from "./Myportal";  

export default class ReactPortal extends React.Component<IReactPortalProps, {}> { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactPortalProps> {  
    //Get modalBody from component properties
    const modalBody = this.props.modalBody;
    
    return (  
      <div >  
        <Myportal modalBody={modalBody} />  
      </div>  
    );  
  }  
}
```

Change `Myportal.tsx` file to:

```
import * as React from "react";
import usePortal from "react-cool-portal";
import "./mystyle.scss";

const Myportal = props => {
  // const { Portal } = usePortal({ containerId: "my-portal-root" });  
  const { Portal, show, hide } = usePortal({ defaultShow: false, containerId: "my-portal-root" });
  const handleClickBackdrop = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
    const { id } = e.target as HTMLDivElement;
    if (id === "modal") hide();
  };

  const { modalBody } = props;

  return (
    <div className="App">

      <button className="btn" onClick={show} type="button">
        Who we are
      </button>
      &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
      <button className="btn" onClick={show} type="button">
        Our value
      </button>
      <Portal>
        <div
          id="modal"
          className="modal"
          onClick={handleClickBackdrop}
          tabIndex={-1}
        >
          <div
            className="modal-dialog"
            role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="modal-label"
            aria-modal="true"
          >
            <div className="modal-header">

              <button
                className="modal-close"
                onClick={hide}
                type="button"
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body">
              <p> {modalBody} </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Portal>
    </div>

  );
};
export default Myportal;
```

**Documentation**: [Make your SharePoint client-side web part configurable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/integrate-with-property-pane)

Also, I would recommend you to look at the code provided in below samples & see how others are implementing property pane in their web parts.

**Similar web part samples**:

1. [Links webpart](https://github.com/pnp/sp-starter-kit/tree/master/solution/src/webparts/links)
2. [Custom Links](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-custom-links)

Comment: thanks a lot for the very helpful reply.. but how i can allow the Description field to accept HTML code? or to render it as Rich Text editor ? is this possible? thanks

Comment: You can paste the HTML in same text box control & bind it in `Myportal.tsx` file like: `<div className="modal-body" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={modalBody} />`

Comment: If you want more advance controls, you can import available controls from `@microsoft/sp-property-pane` library OR you can use [@pnp/spfx-property-controls](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/) OR [build custom controls for the property pane](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/build-custom-property-pane-controls) as per your requirements.

Comment: but i could not find any Rich Text field type inside this link @ https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/ can u advice? thanks

Comment: Then you have to [build custom controls for the property pane](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/build-custom-property-pane-controls) >> where you can use [PnP RichText control](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/controls/RichText/) OR any react library which support rich text field as per your requirements.

Comment: but i want the Rich Text editor to be part of the Web Part configuration setting.. i am not planning to build a Rich Text editor web part.. did u get my point?

Comment: Yes, I know. Can you please check [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/build-custom-property-pane-controls) in detail once again? This step by step guide shows you how you can build custom control inside property pane >> Here they have used Fluent UI (Office UI fabric) `Dropdown` control & added it to property pane.

Comment: Similarly, you have to build you own custom control using any library you want & add it to the property pane (`getPropertyPaneConfiguration()` method) like [given here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/build-custom-property-pane-controls#render-the-item-web-part-property-in-the-property-pane).

Comment: but none of the example show how to render multiple-line of text which accept HTML code or how to render Rich text editor inside the web part configuration settings.. am i correcT?

Comment: Hmm, yes. Not everyone has such requirements and you will not find ready made code/example for every scenario/requirements.

Comment: i am still trying to seek a way to show rich text inside the Popup instead of showing plain-text only..

Comment: You can try this for now: You can paste the HTML in same text box control & bind it in Myportal.tsx file like: `<div className="modal-body" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={modalBody} />`

Answer (score 0):

To be clear:
You are looking for code that will permit the entry of arbitrary code that will display itself as a modal pop-up.
Are you seeking that the parent to the pop-up be the window object or the body object?
If the former, why not use the window.confirm
Object?
Or are you being cheeky and super-slick?

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i do not want the user to add arbitrary code... i just want to allow them to add simple text or HTML .. something similar to the approach used in this example https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/modal-popup-in-spfx/ except that i want end users to be able to add the text, instead of having it hard-coded inside the web part code.. i hope this clarify my question to you..